# TYPO3 Contactform log

Tags: logging, typo3

I am using the standard contact form in a TYPO3 11-Installation.
I wonder if the mails, especially the sender-ID are logged somewhere?

Under: typo3temp/var/log it is only logged for the last 2 days.
Needed are 7 days backwards

Comment: This extension here helps with logging of info with EXT:Form. It's worth giving a try, https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/formlog

Comment: thank you! I will try this. But this want solve my problem for the moment because i'd like to get some info for the last two weeks.